# problems setting up instapy in raspberry pi

Tags: selenium, raspberry-pi, webdriver, geckodriver, instapy

I have a perfectly worling instapy bot on windows, I want to run the same thing on raspberry pi , I have bought a 3b model, and followed all insytructions as stated here https://github.com/InstaPy/instapy-docs/blob/master/How_Tos/How_to_Raspberry.md

all the above commands have executed but I am getting a few errors,
I belive there is some problem with the webdriver but I cant resolve it here is the error,

```
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
INFO [2021-06-04 19:53:06] [spotify.no_ads]  Workspace in use: "/home/pi/Desktop/instagram/final-bot/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 168, in <module>
    headless_browser=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 338, in __init__
    geckodriver_log_level,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 127, in set_selenium_local_session
    options=firefox_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Desktop/instagram/final-bot#
```

I have never used a raspi before ,so if you ask specifications ,also please tell me how can I find it

firefox version: `78.11.0esr (32-bit)`
geckodriver version: `geckodriver 0.23.0 ( 2018-10-04)`